# aggregating columns of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame as follows:

```
>data
    ID     Orginal   Modified
    Sam_1    M         K
    Sam_1    K         M
    Sam_1    I         J
    Sam_1    M         K
    Sam_1    K         M
    Sam_2    K         M
    Sam_2    M         K
    Sam_3    J         P
    Sam_4    K         M
    Sam_4    M         K
    Sam_4    P         J
```

I would like to count the for every sample number times M in column "Original" is converted to K in column "Modified" and "K" ins the column "Original" to "M" in columns Modified and report it in tab delim text file as follows:

```
>newdata
    ID     M_to_K_counts  K_to_M_counts 
    Sam_1     2                2 
    Sam_2     1                1
    Sam_3     0                0
    Sam_4     1                1
```

I tried following code but it failed:

```
counts=function()
{
for(i in 1:dim(rnaseqmut)[1])
{
  mk_counts=0
  km_counts=0
  if(data$Original[i]=='M' & data$Modified[i]== 'K')
    {
       mk_counts=mk_counts+1
    }
  if(data$Original[i]=='K' & data$Modified[i]== 'M')
    {
       km_counts=km_counts+1
    }
}
print(mk_counts)
print(km_counts)
}
```

How can I achieve my desired format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`).  Grouped by the 'ID' column, we get the `sum` of elements that are 'M' for the 'Orginal' and 'K' for 'Modified' ('MtoKcount'), similarly the 'KtoMcount' is got by doing the reverse.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(MtoKcount=sum(Orginal=='M' & Modified=='K'),
               KtoMcount = sum(Orginal=='K' & Modified=='M')), by =  ID]
#       ID MtoKcount KtoMcount
#1: Sam_1         2         2
#2: Sam_2         1         1
#3: Sam_3         0         0
#4: Sam_4         1         1
```

---

Another option is `table` from `base R`.  We `paste` the columns other than the 'ID' column (`do.call(paste0, data[-1])`) and get the frequency count using `table`.  Then, we subset the table output ('tbl') that have only 'KM' or 'MK' as its column names

```
 tbl <- table(data$ID,do.call(paste0, data[-1]))[,c('KM', 'MK')]
 tbl
 #      KM MK
 #Sam_1  2  2
 #Sam_2  1  1
 #Sam_3  0  0
 #Sam_4  1  1
```

As @user295691 mentioned in the comments, we can change the column names while `paste`ing.

```
  tbl <- with(data, table(ID, paste0(Orginal, "_to_", Modified,"_counts"))) 
  tbl[,c('K_to_M_counts', 'M_to_K_counts')]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("Sam_1", "Sam_1", "Sam_1", "Sam_1", 
"Sam_1", 
"Sam_2", "Sam_2", "Sam_3", "Sam_4", "Sam_4", "Sam_4"), Orginal = c("M", 
"K", "I", "M", "K", "K", "M", "J", "K", "M", "P"), Modified = c("K", 
"M", "J", "K", "M", "M", "K", "P", "M", "K", "J")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Orginal", "Modified"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: To get closer to the requested format, `with(data, table(ID, paste0(Orginal, "_to_", Modified,"_counts")))`

Comment: @user295691  Thanks for your comments.  I added that in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Base R using `xtabs`. Desired shape/subsetting requires transposing and fiddling with container type classes.

```
d<-as.matrix(ftable(xtabs(Count~Orginal+Modified+ID,transform(data,Count=1))))
as.data.frame(t(d))[,c("M_K","K_M")]
```

```
      M_K K_M
Sam_1   2   2
Sam_2   1   1
Sam_3   0   0
Sam_4   1   1
```

Comment: xtabs seems like overkill; `ftable(paste(Orginal, Modified, sep="_") ~ ID, data=asdf)` does the trick as well.

Comment: Yes, [akrun has a short table version in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31880283/1756702). Saw that edit after I posted or I would not have bothered.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
x <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("Sam_1", 5), rep("Sam_2", 2), "Sam_3", rep("Sam_4", 3)), 
 Orginal = c("M", "K", "I", "M", "K", "K", "M", "J", "K", "M", "P"), 
 Modified = c("K", "M", "J", "K", "M", "M", "K", "P", "M", "K", "J"))

x %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(M_to_K_counts = length((Orginal == "M")[Modified == "K"]), 
             K_to_M_counts = length((Orginal == "K")[Modified == "M"]))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

#      ID M_to_K_counts K_to_M_counts
# 1 Sam_1             2             2
# 2 Sam_2             1             1
# 3 Sam_3             0             0
# 4 Sam_4             1             1
```